# how can I add percentage symbol into a pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(process = structure(16:1, .Label = c("A", "AA", 
"AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA", "B", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "BBBBB", "BBBBBB", 
"C", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC", "CCCCC"), class = "factor"), percentage = c(1.869158879, 
0.934579439, 5.046728972, 1.682242991, 0.747663551, 15.70093458, 
1.869158879, 3.551401869, 3.738317757, 0.373831776, 2.61682243, 
1.121495327, 13.45794393, 21.30841121, 14.76635514, 11.21495327
), lab.ypos = c(0.9345794395, 2.3364485985, 5.327102804, 8.6915887855, 
9.9065420565, 18.130841122, 26.9158878515, 29.6261682255, 33.2710280385, 
35.327102805, 36.822429908, 38.6915887865, 45.981308415, 63.364485985, 
81.40186916, 94.392523365)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

I plot it like the following

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=percentage, fill=process))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+ 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+ 
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = round(percentage)), color = "white")
```

I basically want to show the numbers bold and with a % sign 
is there a way to do that?

Comment: @d.b you are amazing but is there a way to avoid the overlap numbers? because when I do it seems like putting them together

Comment: You can use `percent_format` from `scales`

Comment: @d.b no I need them all . basically I want to show the percentage portion , if you have a better option, you can discard the lab.ypos and make another one

Comment: @akrun can you give me a solution please?

Comment: Doesn't address the code itself, but the fact that there are so many pie slice that you can't label them without overlaps is a good sign that a pie chart isn't the way to go here and why many data viz folks will argue against their use with more than a couple categories

Comment: But usefulness aside, how do you intend to position labels so they don't overlap? Like where would you want to put them?

Comment: @Camille I really don't know, if I show them by a line, it also will be messy ! so if no solution then I remove those % and just plot as number

Comment: Can't you replace your pie chart with a bar chart? [There are a number of reasons pie charts are bad](https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/pie.html).

Comment: It seems like you should first figure out exactly what you're trying to display and how, including the options you want to deal with overlapping labels, and then revisit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `adorn_pct_formatting()` function from the `janitor` package to format your values as percentages. The function will alter every numeric column so you'll need to isolate your percentage column prior to applying `adorn_pct_formatting()`. It also multiplies your values by 100 for you so you'd need to remove your formatting as well by dividing it out first. I'd recommend creating a new variable that is specifically formatted to be the label in your plot.

```
# library tidyverse
# library janitor

df <- df %>%                                    # overwrites your original data object
  mutate(label = percentage/100) %>%            # creates the label column
  select(process, label) %>%                    # isolates the label column for percent formatting
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>%                    # applies the formatting to your numeric columns
  bind_cols(list(lab.ypos = df$lab.ypos,        # appends your other numeric columns
                 percentage = df$percentage))

head(df)
  process label   lab.ypos percentage
1   CCCCC  1.9%  0.9345794  1.8691589
2    CCCC  0.9%  2.3364486  0.9345794
3     CCC  5.0%  5.3271028  5.0467290
4      CC  1.7%  8.6915888  1.6822430
5       C  0.7%  9.9065421  0.7476636
6  BBBBBB 15.7% 18.1308411 15.7009346
```

You can see that you now have a new column that is specifically formatted as a label for your plot. Now you can run your original `ggplot` code while only replacing the label argument as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=percentage, fill=process))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+ 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+ 
  geom_text(aes(y = lab.ypos, label = label), color = "white")
```

As for label placement, there is no easy way to automatically dodge the position in a dynamic way without loading another package. I'd recommend using the `geom_label_repel()` function from the `ggrepel` package rather than `geom_text()`.

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=percentage, fill=process))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+ 
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+ 
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = label, y = lab.ypos), nudge_x = .5)
```

Without the `nudge_x` argument, the labels will remain inside the bounds of the pie chart. You can alter the value of `nudge_x` to change how far the labels are "nudged" outside of the chart.

Comment: What's the advantage over just `paste0(round(percentage), "%")`? One line of base R to do what you've got in 4 lines plus loading `janitor`. And the OP brings up later that the issue is actually placement of labels so they don't overlap (it wasn't clear at first)

Comment: It's only 4 lines of code because the OP has some of the percent formatting in place already. Without multiplying the percentage column by 100 beforehand, it is essentially equivalent to `paste0(round(percentage*100), "%")`, which is more work than `adorn_pct_formatting()`. So, it is more work for the current problem, but it will expedite the process if the OP has to go create similar figures in the future. As for label placement, I'll update my answer.

Comment: They already have their percentages multiplied by 100, so that bit is done. I just can't see a situation where it would be worthwhile. Also doesn't seem like quite what `adorn_pct_formatting` is intended for